# How do I figure out what is causing android.os.TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: android

I have an exception that is happening a lot on Android 7, and very little on version below that. I have no idea how to reproduce it, I've only seen the reports on crashlytics.

I don't really pass data between activities or with services. I do save the state of some WebViews on the `onSaveInstanceState` method of one of my activities, but I have been doing that for years, I'm not sure why it would be causing issues all of the sudden.

Any ideas?

This is the exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1405624 bytes
       at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4156)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Caused by android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1405624 bytes
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Binder.java)
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:628)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:4149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4148)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup! As of Android 7.0 (Nougat) [the system will crash if the data in `onSaveInstanceState` is too large](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#other).

You'll have to figure out another way to save and restore state.

http://blog.sqisland.com/2016/09/transactiontoolargeexception-crashes-nougat.html

Note this comment from Dianne Hackborn:

> Dianne Hackborn September 18, 2016 at 10:52 AM
>
> It is more complicated than a fixed size limit. Each process has a
>   fixed buffer for receiving incoming transactions, whose size is 1MB.
>   So technically you could say the maximum size is 1MB, but that assumes
>   there are no other IPCs happening. In practice, you should never have
>   a size anywhere close to that, or you run the risk of occasionally
>   failing when there are a number of other concurrent IPCs in progress.
>
> For the specific case of saved state, you also want to keep this small
>   because whatever you provide here is data the system needs to hold on
>   to in the system process for as long as the user can ever navigate
>   back to that activity (even if the activity's process is killed).
>
> So I would recommend keeping the saved state well less than 100K, and
>   really less than 50K, and in most cases much less than even that.

Comment: Note that lots of things add to saved state size - fragment state, for example.

Comment: Thank you for all the info. I might not even need to save those webviews. I'll just have to test next week to see what all I can remove.

Comment: Yah, in general its not a good idea to pass around views. The are large, and leak prone. See if you can pass a url or something like that instead.